# Type-checking while using naked lambda expression for java comparator

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I encountered the following issue with Java while attempting to use a "naked" lambda expression as part of `Comparator.comparing()` expression.

This following statement works as expected:

```
Comparator<String> secondCharCmp = Comparator.comparing(s -> s.charAt(1));
```

However, the following doesn't:

```
Comparator<String> secondCharThenStringCmp = Comparator
        .comparing(s -> s.charAt(1))
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

And, when I tried to "type" the lambda as follows, it works again:

```
Comparator<String> secondCharThenStringCmp = Comparator
        .comparing((String s) -> s.charAt(1))
        .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

---

My confusion is the following: while Java is able to infer that my lambda (and hence `Comparator`) is for String type in the first statement, why is it unable to infer so in the second case (and I'm forced to supply a type as in the third)?

In these examples, how does Java work behind the scenes to infer the types in the three statements?

Comment: Please fix "comapre" -> "compare" first of all.

Comment: Good catch @lexicore, no idea how I made those typos...

Comment: I suspect it would also work if you used `Comparator.<String>naturalOrder()`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Unfortunately, that also doesn't work... hence my confusion about the whole type-inference going on in this case.

Comment: What works is `Comparator<String> secondCharThenStringCmp = Comparator.<String, Character>comparing(s -> s.charAt(1)).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());`.

Comment: Even better is would be `Comparator.<String>comparingInt(s -> s.charAt(1)).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());` to avoid unnecessary wrapping/unwrapping of `char`.

Comment: @lexicore Thanks for the explanation! I just double-checked the source code of `Comparator` and confirmed that `thenComparing` does not take a type parameter... which means I'll need to supply necessary type arguments to `comparing`/`compareInt` to tell the `Comparator` to act on Strings. Is my understanding roughly correct?

Comment: @Zz'Rot I would not say so. You basically imply that type parameters are required for type inference to work, I don't think it is correct. And in any case, this would be an oversimplification. Pleare refer to the question I've linked as duplicate.